# How to store kafka topic data into cassandra

Tags: apache-kafka, cassandra

I have installed cassandra using this reference link
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-apache-cassandra-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Also I have installed kafka into my ubuntu 18.04 machine using
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-kafka-on-ubuntu-18-04

Now I want to store kafka topic data to cassandra database.
If any one have idea please help me.

I have done so many research in it from last 3 days but didn't get success in it. I implemented cassandra sink using this link but it is not working.
so please check details before you down rate the question.

http://itechseeker.com/en/tutorials-2/apache-cassandra/connecting-kafka-to-cassandra-sink/

Comment: "but didn't get success in it" … "but it is not working" … please can you update your question to detail exactly *what* you did (not just links to a tutorial), and *what* error you got?

Comment: Hello @robin I am new to Cassandra and kafka so started with their  installation. I successfully installed them. In kafka I have created one producer and consumer for test data. So basically kafka producer and consumer is working fine. Now I want to save consumer data to cassandra data sour r. I tried tutorial but didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DataStax Kafka Connector](https://docs.datastax.com/en/kafka/doc/index.html) that is built for Kafka Connect framework (it's free for DSE & OSS Cassandra). It doesn't require you to write the code for writing from Kafka to Cassandra - just provide the configuration file.  The connector is heavily optimized for throughput, plus it has many other useful options, as ability to write from single topic to multiple Cassandra tables (data denormalization), etc.

You can find more examples of connector's usage in [the following repository](https://github.com/datastax/kafka-examples).

Comment: Is it open source or I have to purchase license for it?

Comment: it's not an open source, but you can freely use it

Comment: Hello alex data sink is working fine by above connector.
but every time I hava to run this command "bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/dse-sink.properties
" for sink. Is there any way to auto sink without pasting this command every time to console ?

Comment: The Standalone mode is mostly used for testing. You need to use distributed mode of Kafka Connect framework, as described here: https://docs.datastax.com/en/kafka/doc/kafka/operations/kafkaStartDistributedMode.html