# Is there a sample example of opensource Kafka Cassandra connector configuration?

Tags: apache-kafka, cassandra, datastax

We are feeding events (logs) from Logstash to Apache Cassandra using the [PerimeterX](https://github.com/PerimeterX/logstash-output-cassandra) Cassandra Logstash out plugin. We have hit the max throughput of the plugin to be 8K as it opens only 2 connections to Cassandra whereas Cassandra has a much higher throughput (for consuming data) and we expecting a throughput on the actual system to be 30K or higher.

*Here throughput is the capacity to consume the incoming events, which is x units/sec*

Hence we planned to introduced Kafa in the middle which has a 45K throughput with Logstash output.

We are looking for help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60947106/how-to-store-kafka-topic-data-into-cassandra) stack overflow post. We could configure the connector JAR as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/kafka/doc/kafka/install/kafkaInstall.html). But there is no proper guide or current documentation is very confusing and goes in a loop with the configuration requirement. We don't see the plugin being called when Kafka is running with the target topic.

**Some help on what is the correct configuration, or some documentation info on Cassandra keyspaces will be helpful.**

Comment: look onto https://github.com/datastax/kafka-sink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After placing the JAR as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/kafka/doc/kafka/install/kafkaInstall.html)
We need to run Kafka connect which will show all the connectors configured.
To turn on Kafka connect run the below command (Kafka connect in distributed mode)

> bin/connect-distributed.sh config/connect-distributed.properties

Kafka connect has a REST API service available at http://localhost:8083
using this REST API you can configure your connectors.

To register the connector use the below API

> POST /connectors – creates a new connector; the request body should be a JSON object containing a string name field and an object config field with the connector configuration parameters

The JSON sample to register the connector is present kafka-connect-cassandra-sink-1.4.0.tar.gz file.

The [official-documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_rest) provides a list with all endpoints.

More info available [here](https://www.baeldung.com/kafka-connectors-guide)